# Get Role in a View MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 and i've created a view with create/read actions using EF.
I'm trying to get the role of the current user in the view. I have this code in the "Create" view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoUtilizador)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.TextBox("TipoUtilizador", System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser().Single())
    </div>
```

But when i click create, the parameter goes with the name "TipoUtilizador" and not with the role's name (in this case the user has the role "Student").
How can i get the role and when i click submit the role's name goes in TipoUtilizador parameter?

Comment: The role name 'Student' is displayed on the form already when the form is loaded, not later when the submit button is clicked, is it not the current state?

Comment: When the button is clicked the state turns into "TipoUtilizador"

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the assignment into the HTTP GET action of the controller:

```
model.TipoUtilizador = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser().Single();
```

and change the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TipoUtilizador)
</div>
```

It would be easier now to debug the controller and see what value is assigned.

Comment: the value assigned continues to be "TipoUtilizador"

Comment: if the `GetRolesForUser()` method, when debugged in the controller, returns a single role "TipoUtilizador" then probably the user is configured for such a row in the Role provider (and also probably this issue is not connected to the UI - or View). One thing to check would be to have a look in the RoleProvider and the DB it uses if the user really has such a row, but it is strange, since it has the Student role, as you have written.

Comment: Yes the role for that user is Student. In the textbox it appears "Student" but when i click create in the table for that row appears "TipoUtilizador"

Comment: could you also add the code for the HTML form including the button?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik, That should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TipoUtilizador)` :)